# Prove $0$ is not a limit point of certain set

Tags: general-topology

I would like to know if my reasoning is correct for the following problem.
Let's suppose we have a connected set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that:

1.- $\forall U \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, such that, U is closed, we have that $U \cap  M$ is a compact subset of $M$.

2.- $M$ and the plane $z=0$ are disjoint.

Then $0$ is not a limit point of $M$

---

We can assume without loss of generality that $M$ is in the halfspace given by z<0.
By 1. we have that $\forall r>0, \hspace{0.15cm}$$  B[0,r] \cap M$ is compact.
In particular, $B[0,\frac{1}{n}] \cap M$ is compact $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. For $n$ sufficiently large we have that $B[0,\frac{1}{n}] \cap M = \emptyset$, since $\emptyset \not \in M$.
Then $$\exists \eta \in \mathbb{N} / B(0,\frac{1}{\eta})\setminus \{0\} \cap M \subset B[0,\frac{1}{\eta}] \cap M = \emptyset$$

Hence $0 \not \in M'$

Comment: Can't you just say that $M$ is compact since it is the intersection of the closure of $M$ and $M$ itself, so it is closed and bounded. Therefore it must contain its limit points but $0$ is not in $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to show is *precisely* that for sufficiently large $n$, $B[0,1/n]\cap M=\emptyset$.

Hint: by contradiction, assume there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $M$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$. Then the set $U=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ is closed.

Comment: So now, we take $U \cap M$ =$\{x_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ which is not closed since it doesn't contain all its limits points, hence it's not compact as $\mathbb{R}^3 $ is Hausdorff, and we get contradiction with 1. So we are done, aren't we?

Comment: @J.Salieri Yes.